# How can I plot a sphere like the picture in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

The coordinate of two points are (0,0,1/3) and (0,0,-1/3) respectively.How can I get this picture in Mathematica?[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.3], Sphere[], Opacity[1], Red, 
  Point[{0, 0, 1/3}], Blue, Point[{0, 0, -1/3}]}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

To break it down:

```
Graphics3D[{
   Opacity[.3],
   Sphere[], 
   Opacity[1], 
   Red, Point[{0, 0, 1/3}], 
   Blue, Point[{0, 0, -1/3}]
}, Axes -> True]
```

We use `Graphics3D` to assemble 3D graphics. We start by setting `Opacity` for the following primitives to be `.3` - roughly what it is in your image. Then we draw a default `Sphere`, which is centred at `{0,0,0}` and has a radius of `1`. Then, we set the `Opacity` back to `1` for the rest of the primitives. Next, our `Red` `Point` at `{0,0,1/3}`, then our `Blue` `Point` at `{0,0,-1/3}`. Finally, as an option to `Graphics3D`, we set `Axes -> True` so that we get the same frame as in your image (`Graphics3D` doesn't show the frame ticks by default).

Comment: Wow,you are so great,thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help. Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem!

Comment: The "Break it down" part is good stuff - much obliged.